# Access persisted store when app is closed

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage, redux-persist

Currently, I am using redux-persist to store data locally. I want to access persited store when app is closed like when a there is a new push notification.

I have tried accessing store using AsyncStorage which is returning null as result.

```
if(AppState.currentState === "background"){
  AsyncStorage.getItem("persist:auth", (err, result) => {
          //result is null
          result = JSON.parse(result);
          if (result && result.isLoggedIn == "true") {
             AsyncStorage.setItem(
                 "persist:profile",
                 {
                   'someKey' : 'value'
                 },
                 (err, profileResult)=>{
                    console.log(profileReuslt)
                  }
             )
          }
    })
}
```

Expected: Ability to manipulate store data in background 
Actual  : Not able to access store data

Please, let me know if there are any other ways to achieve this.

Thanks